# Spherical charge distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I have a pretty simple exercise but i can't get it right using both integration and divergence of potential.

[image]

I first did the field inside the sphere:

$$\vec{E} = \frac{Q\vec{a_R}}{4\pi^2\epsilon_0a^4}\int_v\frac{1}
{R}R^2\sin{\theta}dRd\theta d\phi
$$

Which can be easily calculated to 
$$
\vec{E} = \frac{QR^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0a^4}\vec{a_R}
$$
However, in the answer, there is a $4$ instead of $2$ in my answer. The worst part is that i tried calculating the same thing using 
$$
\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}V
$$
and i got something different from both my previous answer and the correct answer
$$
V = \frac{Q}{4\pi^2\epsilon_0a^4}\int_vR^2\sin{\theta}dRd\theta d\phi = \frac{QR^3}{3\pi\epsilon_0a^4}
$$
Which gives the electric field
$$
\vec{E} = -\vec{a_R} \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{R}} = -\frac{QR^2}{\pi\epsilon_0a^4}\vec{a_R}
$$

I skipped some straighforward integral calculations. I've been staring at this for about an hour now and i cant find any place where those constants could be lost. What have i done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @KyleKanos Oh, i'm sorry for posting here then. Unfortunately there is nobody who i know of who could answer this question.

Comment: Well if you are looking for this kind of help, you  can [take a look at this thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/391) for a list of free online homework help resources.